# F(a)-F(a-) meaning?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have distribution function on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{F},P*)$, $P*=F(x)$. If I integrate $\int_R\mathbb{1}_AdF(x)$, I get the value $F(a)$. On a theorem I encountered the following $F(a)-F(a-)$, considering the dominated converence theorem.

What can $F(a)-F(a-)$ mean? The area just under the point?

Is $F(a)-F(a-)=0$ given the fact $\liminf_{t\to\infty} \int_R\mathbb{1}_AdF_t(x)=lim_{t\to\infty}\int_R\mathbb{1}_AdF(x)$(t indexed to ${a_n}$ convering to a)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually $F(a-)=\lim_{x\to a-}F(x)$.

Comment: $$F(a)-F(a-)=P^*(\{a\})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $F(a) - F(a-)$ is the `jump' in the distribution function at the point $x=a$.  Distribution functions are always right continuous, which means

$$
F(a+) = \lim_{x\downarrow a} F(x) = F(a)
$$ However, they might have a jump discontinuity at $x=a$, meaning

$$
F(a-) =  \lim_{x\uparrow a} F(x)\neq F(a)
$$  The size of the jump is thus $F(a+) - F(a-) = F(a) - F(a-)$.

If $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then $F(a)-F(a-) = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain about that jump? Why does it happen only from below?

Comment: It only happens from below because distribution functions are right continuous.  The proof of this should be in your probability book (or another one) - it's not terribly difficult but a bit technical.  Jumps usually happen when your probability measure has an "atom" i.e. a discrete part ($P(a) \neq 0$)

Comment: So basically this terminology is to generalize the proof to Singular, absolutely continuous and discrete functions, right?

Comment: Yes - if you prove something for distribution functions, you've proved it for all probability measures on $\Bbb{R}$.  Every probability measure on $\Bbb{R}$ (in fact on $\Bbb{R}^n$) has a distribution function (aka CDF).